# Copy or Download an image file from URI to Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, cloud-storage

I have an image uri: https://api.tinify.com/output/im1c1s69phhvjjm6.jpg
This is a result image coming from an online image minification api.

And I wanted to download the minified image to a blob container in Azure.

I did:
var newBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("minified-sample.jpg");
newBlockBlob.StartCopy(new Uri(fileUrl), null, null, null);

What happens then is that all I see is a 0 byte image file in the container.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's an issue with the headers in the image you're trying to copy. I believe `Content-Disposition` header is set for this image. The reason I say this is because when I paste the URL in browser's address bar, instead of displaying the image in the browser I get prompted to download the image.

For copy operation to work, the Blob Service must be able to read the contents of the remote file in response stream when it requests the URL. Because the URL request results in downloading the file, Blob Service is not able to read the contents of the file and thus you get a 0 byte blob.

Edit: This is what I see in Google Postman

[image]